# What is the industry standard definition of $\nabla\cdot\mathfrak{T}$ (del dot a tensor)? Re: MTW

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus, differentiation

In chapter 3 of [MTW's Gravitation](https://press.princeton.edu/titles/11169.html) using the example of a rank-3 tensor $\mathfrak{S}$ they define

$$\text{(divergence of }\mathfrak{S}\text{ on the first slot)}\equiv{\nabla\cdot\mathfrak{S}}$$
Expressed in equation (3.42) this is
$$\nabla\cdot\mathfrak{S}\left[\mathfrak{u},\mathfrak{v}\right]
=\nabla\mathfrak{S}\left[\tilde{\omega}^{\alpha},\mathfrak{u},\mathfrak{v},\mathfrak{e}_{\alpha}\right]
=S^{\alpha}{}_{\beta\gamma,\alpha}u^{\beta}v^{\gamma}.$$
In components:
$$\nabla\cdot\mathfrak{S}=\left\{S^{\alpha}{}_{\beta\gamma,\alpha}\right\}.$$

But in exercise 3.15 they use
$$\nabla\cdot\mathfrak{F}=\left\{F^{\alpha\beta}{}_{,\beta}\right\},$$
which is divergence on the second "slot". And similarly in exercise 3.18.

When taking the "divergence" of a tensor, how is the contraction index determined?

Comment: Is it possible that they're using the antisymmetry of the field strength tensor and you've missed a minus sign?

Comment: I think that people rarely talk about the divergence of a tensor precisely _because_ of this issue. I'm not sure there is a standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The the $\nabla \cdot$ operator generalizes to "four divergence". The four-divergence of the $i^{th}$ component of a rank $n$ tensor $T^{\mu_1, \cdots \mu_i, \cdots, \mu_n}$ is defined as

$$\partial_{\mu_i}T^{\mu_1, \cdots \mu_i, \cdots, \mu_n} \equiv T^{\mu_1, \cdots \mu_i, \cdots, \mu_n}_{, \mu_i} .$$

You then can see that applying this to your specific tensors yields the answers on the RHS. This is written component-wise, but you can add the basis vectors if you like to relate it to the first expression you wrote down. So it appears that MTW just "defines" the less general symbol $\nabla \cdot$ to always be the case where $\mu_i = \mu_1$.

**Edit:** The field strength tensor $F^{\mu\nu} = - F^{\nu\mu}$, and so $\partial_\beta F^{\alpha \beta} = -\partial_\beta F^{\beta\alpha}$ which follows the correct convention if you take into account the minus sign.

Comment: Except MTW don't appear to follow their own definition.  I'm wondering if there is a method to the madness.

Comment: Well, the field strength tensor $F_{\mu\nu} = -F_{ \nu\mu}$ is antisymmetric. So under this definition, it kind of is with respect to the first component, in which case you would expect to pick up a negative sign. I've made an edit to address this concern.

Comment: I accepted the answer because it addresses the question in the subject header using the *definition* given by MTW.  The best I can gather, to MTW it is what they say it is when they say what it is.  In other words, inconsistently defined.